# Does Acetate Cause Major E2 On Tertiary Haloalkanes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

This question really confuses me. I've narrowed it down to E2 being favored in step one (giving 2-methylpropene), but I don't see how a relatively weak base like acetate could cause E2 to be the major product. The only other explanation I could think of is that E2 is a substantial minority product, so the reaction isn't synthetically useful. Am I on the right track? Thanks!
[image: Acetate and 2-bromo-2-methylpropane]

Comment: SN1 then ester hydrolysis.